# Android Studio multiple jar finished with non-zero exit value 2 error

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-volley, android-multidex

I have an app using many modules such as `facebookSDK`, `linkedInSDK` etc. I needed to add one more module that is using `volley` library which is also used in `linkedInSDK`.

It builds successfully but causes:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':splashActivity:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

this error.

app build.gradle:

```
compile(name: 'app-debug', ext: 'aar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

linkedInSDK build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
```

As you can see, they both use volley library. When I remove one of them it throws `cannot be resolved` error in that module.

I tried

```
defaultConfig {

        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

it didn't work.

Both app and linkedInSDK modules needs volley library. How can I build and run it successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving my brand new module to the linkedInSDK and enabling multiDex. So I saw I had two problems, the first one is my project is over 65k Methods which needs multiDex, and library conflict between linkedInSDK and the new SDK.

So here is my linkedInSDK\build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
//compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
compile(name: 'app-debug', ext: 'aar')

}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

So the volley library is used in the same module without conflict. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

I think some solution is present on the 'gradle' [foram](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency/2119). can you please try this.

```
dependencies {

   compile('packageName:name:version') {

   //excluding a particular transitive dependency:
   exclude module: 'name of excluing package' //by artifact name
   }
}
```

*"Happy Coding...!!!"*